# Juice2 npm package throwing TypeError Cannot set property length of [object Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use Juice2 but am getting an `TypeError` that appears to be caused by Juice when using the basic example from the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/juice2) page.

This the 'How to use' example given.

```
juice("/path/to/file.html", function(err, html) {
  console.log(html);
});
```

Here is my code.

```
function juicify() {
      console.log('juice called...');
      var path = './file.html'
      juice(path, function(err, html) {
          console.log(html);
      });
}
```

This is the longer version of the error output to the console.

```
Array.prototype.splice.call(this._childNodes, refChildIndex, 0, newChild);

    TypeError: Cannot set property length of [object Object] which has only a getter
        at core.Node.insertBefore
```

Anyone any ideas what the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using last version of node?

Comment: No I'm using v4.4.7. You think that causing the problem? Cheers!

Comment: Might be, can you upgrade it?

Comment: Can't upgrade at the moment I'm afraid. I'll try downgrading to the previous Juice package.

Comment: Look here https://github.com/apparentlymart/node-angularcontext/issues/5 It seems is an issue with an older version of jsdom

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look!